# Spark Scala Dynamic creation of Serializable object

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, serialization, serializable

I need using a tester for Scala Spark filter, with tester implementing java's Predicate interface and receiving specific class name by arguments.
I'm doing something like this

```
val tester = Class.forName(qualifiedName).newInstance().asInstanceOf[Predicate[T]]
var filtered = rdd.filter(elem => tester.test(elem))
```

The problem is that at runtime i have a Spark "TaskNotSerializable Exception" because my specific Predicate class is not Serializable.

If I do

```
val tester = Class.forName(qualifiedName).newInstance()
             .asInstanceOf[Predicate[T] with Serializable]
var filtered = rdd.filter(elem => tester.test(elem))
```

I get the same error.
If I create tester into rdd.filter call it works:

```
var filtered = rdd.filter { elem => 
    val tester = Class.forName(qualifiedName).newInstance()
             .asInstanceOf[Predicate[T] with Serializable]
    tester.test(elem)
}
```

But I would create a single object (maybe to broadcast) for testing. How can I resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to require the class implements `Serializable`. Note that the `asInstanceOf[Predicate[T] with Serializable]` cast is a lie: it doesn't actually check value is `Serializable`, which is why the second case doesn't produce an error immediately during the cast, and the last one "succeeds".

> But I would create a single object (maybe to broadcast) for testing.

You can't. Broadcast or not, deserialization will create *new* objects on worker nodes. But you can create only a single instance on each partition:

```
var filtered = rdd.mapPartitions { iter => 
    val tester = Class.forName(qualifiedName).newInstance()
             .asInstanceOf[Predicate[T]]
    iter.filter(tester.test)
}
```

It will actually perform better than serializing the `tester`, sending it, and deserializing it would, since it's strictly less work.

Comment: Oh, thank you for the suggest! But i get two errors:

`No ClassTag available for T Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.`

`not enough arguments for method mapPartitions: (implicit evidence$6: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$6. Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.`

I added the preservePartitions boolean (as false), but i cannot understand what is asking (evidence is undocumented in API)

Comment: Some Spark operations require implicit `ClassTag` parameters. See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html for description of `ClassTag`s, or just search for more information. Here, assuming `T` is a type parameter of your method/class, you should just need to add `: ClassTag` to it (i.e. if this code is in `def foo[T](...)` method, replace it with `def foo[T: ClassTag]`). Compile and update any callers which give a compilation error similarly.

Comment: mmh what function should be foo[T]..? I use test(T) method from java.util.function.Predicate to filter, the filtered elements are also a java class, so I don't know where to put the classTag marker

Comment: Wherever `T` in the `asInstanceOf[Predicate[T]]` code is declared.